# error LNK1169 для векторов в хедере

Tags: c++, vector, компоновщик

Нигде, кроме мейна не могу объявить вектор. Т.е. не конкретно вектор, а любой темплейт вообще. Если я объявляю, например 
`vector<int> Ceache;` в Animation.h, и напрямую сделаю инклюд в мейне, то получу следующее: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же пишу в Main.cpp - то без проблем, всё работает.
inb4: #pragma once в Animation.h написана, проблема не в этом.

Comment: Подумайте над тем, чтобы избавиться от глобальных переменных.

Answer (score 4):

Это предложение

```
vector<int> Ceache;
```

является не только объявлением имени `Ceache`, как имеющего тип `vector<int>`, но и является определением соответствующего объекта для этого имени.

Поэтому помещая это предложение в заголовок, и включая этот заголовок в несколько модулей вы тем самым определяете соответствующий объект с этим именем в каждой единице трансляции, в которую этот заголовок включен. Соответственно редактор не знает, как выделять память для этих объектов с одним и тем же именем.

Вам следует превратить это определение в заголовке только в объявление имени `Ceache`, посредством указания спецификатора `extern`:

```
extern vector<int> Ceache;
```

А определить соответствующий объект только в одном модуле вне заголовочного файла, как, например,

```
vector<int> Ceache;
```

Тогда соответствующая единица трансляции будет выглядеть как

```
#include "YourHeader.h"
/* здесь идут объявления, вставляемые из заголовка ^/
extern vector<int> Ceache;

/* а это уже код, написанный в самом вашем модуле */
vector<int> Ceache;
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

в **Animation.h** объявите vector как extern:

```
extern std::vector<int> Ceache;
```

в **Animation.cpp** объявите vector без extern:

```
std::vector<int> Ceache;
```